# WCF basicHttpsBinding warning: "is invalid according to its datatype"

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-endpoint

I created a WCF application, starting with basicHttpBinding.  In app.config, I have the following endpoint configured:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="JMMEcommerceService.IJMMEcommerceService">
  <identity>
    <dns value="localhost" />
  </identity>
</endpoint>
```

This builds fine.  However, I want to change the protocol from HTTP to HTTPS.  If I change the endpoint declaration to:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="JMMEcommerceService.IJMMEcommerceService">
  <identity>
    <dns value="localhost" />
  </identity>
</endpoint>
```

(note: the only change is basicHttpBinding -> basicHttpsBinding)

I get the following warning a build time:

```
WCF configuration validation warning: The 'binding' attribute is invalid - The value 'basicHttpsBinding' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceBindingType'.
```

Why would I get this warning?  Is there something else that I need to change?

Here is the full app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="JMMEcommerceService.JMMEcommerceService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="JMMEcommerceService.IJMMEcommerceService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/JMMEcommerceService/JMMEcommerceService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `basicHttpsBinding` does not appear to exist in .NET 4.0, only in 4.5. Which version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: Are you hosting in IIS? Which .NET version is configured on the site?

Comment: No, not IIS.  This is all on the development machine, which is running Windows 8 and VS 2012 Pro, so it has definitely has .NET 4.5 configured.  Again, the warning happens a build time.

Comment: Can you post the web.config? Simplified?

Comment: It's not a web app.  I have added the full app.config to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to enable HTTPS for your service, but not for your Metadata, you have to provide another base address for your HTTP-based Metadata Exchange endpoint.

```
<baseAddresses>
  <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/JMMEcommerceService/JMMEcommerceService/" />
  <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8734/Design_Time_Addresses/JMMEcommerceService/JMMEcommerceService/" />
</baseAddresses>
```

Please note, that you have to assign another port too (8734). Two protocols can not use the same port!

PS: Do not forget to assign the correct certificate to the port 8733

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.